# Modular/Plugin Framework In ASP.Net MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mef

I want to create a web application using ASP.Net MVC5. It is a big enterprise application and having lots of modules, earlier i worked on Siverlight and use the Prism architecture.

I already Google this and found lots of posts but most of them are at least 1 year old so just want to know Is there something new coming introduced which help me to implement the plugin framework.

Comment: Similar answer is here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21017036/mef-with-mvc-4-or-5-pluggable-architecture-2014

Answer (score 7):

Hi I was also in search of similar things. I found below helpful.

[MVC plug in architecture](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/614767/NET-ASP-NET-MVC-plug-in-architecture-with-embedded)

[MEF in MVC](http://kennytordeur.blogspot.in/2012/08/mef-in-aspnet-mvc-4-and-webapi.html)