# MEF in MVC 5 and WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, mef

I've tried to integrate MEF in a MVC 5 & WebApi Project, like described here: http://kennytordeur.blogspot.ch/2012/08/mef-in-aspnet-mvc-4-and-webapi.html .

The code works for importing dependencies in a normal MVC controller. But it doesn’t work with WebApi controllers.

Dou you know a working example (using MEF to import dependencies in MVC and WebApi controllers) ?

Comment: I'm facing exactly this problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: No I haven't found a solution ... I ended up using Autofac and so far I'm happy with it

Comment: Try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21017036/mef-with-mvc-4-or-5-pluggable-architecture-2014), controllers have been handled and custom view engine as well