# A MEF Plugin for MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, mef

I'm using MEF to create a MVC 5 app that support plugins.  Using a IControllerFactory and IOC from MEF I've got it working so that `/app/specialcontroller/action` calls the action and controller from the other dll (plugin).

The problem i have is that when the `bundles` and `content` are loaded, the controller factory is failing because `content` and `bundles` aren't exported from the plugin.

What I would like to happen is to use the Default factory for certain "controller" names.

Is this possible?

This is the answer I based it on...
[MEF with MVC 4 or 5 - Pluggable Architecture (2014)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21017036/mef-with-mvc-4-or-5-pluggable-architecture-2014)

When including `app/bundles/jquery` I want it to use the MVC controller for `bundles`

Hope that makes sense, thanks

Comment: As I understand, you want to add css and js files from the plugins to the Bundle Table?

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario I have used the following controller factory in one of my projects earlier -

```
namespace CaterPiller.WebClient.Factories
{
    public class MvcControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
    {
        private readonly CompositionContainer _container;
        public MvcControllerFactory(CompositionContainer container)
        {
            _container = container;
        }

        protected override IController GetControllerInstance(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
        {
            if(controllerType == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            var export = _container.GetExports(controllerType, null, null).FirstOrDefault();
            return null == export
                       ? base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType)
                       : (IController) export.Value;
        }

        public override void ReleaseController(IController controller)
        {
            ((IDisposable) controller).Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

for `bundles` and `content`, the controller type is usually `null`, so I just returned null for them -

```
if(controllerType == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }
```

and got them served by the default controller. I had my other urls served by controllers only `bundles` and `contents` were not, so this worked for me. Probably not the best solution but this solved my problem back then while using `MEF` for creating controller factory. You can try this solution and this might help you.

Comment: My implementation only has CreateController, ReleaseController and GetControllerSessionBehavior. No GetControllerInstance. Am I missing something?

Comment: GenControllerInstance is the actual resolver for your controller classes (Because with MEF I was using Service Locator Pattern).

Comment: I understand that, but there is no GetControllerInstance TO override, only CreateController, ReleaseController and GetControllerSessionBehavior

Comment: @user3036342 Not sure about your implementation, this project of mine is 1.5 year old, so it was probably mvc4, not sure if they changed it on mvc5.